# How get -nan on C++ 14?

Tags: c++, c++14, nan

I need to get `-nan` used only `double` type and arithmetics.

So, the code should be like that:

```
double a = ...

cout << a << endl;

-nan
```

where `...` is some expression.

Comment: "Need". Is this a homework requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use [`std::nan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan), e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double a = -std::nan("1");

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/RVryeu)</kbd>

Comment: I will mark this question like answer but I said that you need use only arithmetics, so the answer is (INFINITY_NUMBER / INFINITY_NUMBER) = -NaN, but I think you made this answer only cause of my bad English

Comment: Sorry, yes, I probably didn't interpret your question as you intended. What is the reason for this constraint ? Performance ? Can you not just initialise the value as a constant ?

Answer (score 2):

If your platform uses IEEE754 floating point then `0.0 / 0.0` will evaluate to NaN.

Alternatively you can use `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`, having checked that `std::numeric_limits<double>::has_quiet_NaN` is `true` on your platform.

Really there is no such thing as a signed `NaN`, although a representation of `NaN` might contain a sign bit which could be picked up by the `std::cout`. Perhaps on your platform `-0.0 / 0.0` generates a "negative" `NaN`. The result of `cout << a` for the case where `a` is `NaN` is entirely compiler-dependent.

Comment: This is the only `constexpr` way.

Comment: Indeed. I don't like the `std::nan("1");` route for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

To get a negative nan, simply OR a NaN representation with 0x80000000. You'll have to play about with casting the address to an unsigned char * or long long *, or course.